# Why does my bathroom light go off and on after switch gets turned on

Tags: electrical

I am curious to know if there is an electrical short in our home. I experience turning on light switches and then light goes off at times. It sounds 
Like my tv sparks at times.

Comment: Could you maybe explain this a bit more clearly? What exactly happens? How often does it happen (eg, every time or one in 50 times)? Is it just the bathroom light, or are other lights in your house doing this? What type of lights (CFL, LED, incandescent)? What is the age of the house (or wiring, if you know of renovations being done)? Is your TV actually sparking or just making a sound? Is this while it's off? Does the TV issue happen while lights are flickering or turning off or whatever, or does it happen independently?

Comment: I will go into the bathroom and turn the

Comment: I would go into the bathroom and turn on the switch, light goes on. Continue walking and light goes off walk back to switch and push up on it, light goes on and stays on.  Light has 6 bulbs,regular big round bulds

Comment: Electrical arcs from bad connections or poor contact shorts create broadband hash noise. If you are hearing this sound on TV audio, Radio audio especially on an AM radio, you need to hunt it down before it causes a fire. A bad electrical switch with burned contacts could also cause this.

Answer (score 3):

Based on saying you can push up on the switch and the light turns back on, the switch sounds like it's faulty and needs to be replaced.

This is a pretty easy DIY job. You need a new switch ($1-2 at any hardware store) and some basic tools, post back if you need help with the specifics.

If you've never done any electrical work before, please read up first and use ample caution. Electricity can be extremely dangerous, and it's why even people like me that have been doing it for years still carry around and use a non-contact voltage detector ($10-15) every time we go to touch any wiring, just to be really, *really* sure it's not live.

Comment: +1 for using a non-contact voltage detector.  Our house had a faulty breaker so even though we thought the circuit was off... it wasn't.  Thankfully we had one of those tools and found out before learning the hard way. Those tools are waaaaaaay worth it.